# Amcharts put into html

Tags: amcharts

It is very strange that last time I run the program everything is ok, but this time it does not work, the result web page a empty and I really don't know where make the error.(Sorry only add some words to Thank you Thank you Thank you)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>My first stock chart</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="amcharts/style.css" type="text/css">

<style>
    #chartdiv
    {
        width       : 100%;
        height      : 500px;
        font-size   : 11px;
    }
</style>

<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/dataloader/dataloader.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

AmCharts.loadFile("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/22300.csv", {}, function (response) {

        /**
         * Parse CSV
         */
        var data = AmCharts.parseCSV(response, {
            "useColumnNames": true
        });

        /**
         * Create the chart
         */
        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "light",
            "dataProvider": data,
            "valueAxes": [{
                "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                "gridAlpha": 0.2,
                "dashLength": 0
            }],
            "gridAboveGraphs": true,
            "startDuration": 1,
            "graphs": [{
                "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
                "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                "type": "column",
                "valueField": "visits"
            }],
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "zoomable": false
            },
            "categoryField": "country",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "tickPosition": "start",
                "tickLength": 20
            }
        });

    });

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in browser's console? The code looks fine. You can also add `console.log(data)` right after your parseCSV line to see if your CSV parsed correctly.

Comment: Tried your code. Works perfectly: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d30bf8964f80003fd110798753678dd5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV file is probably cached now in your browser, this causes `Amcharts` to immediately create the Chart. Unfortunately the div container doesn't exist yet. Either move your chart initialisation script tag below the chart div or wrap it in a `DOMContentLoaded` eventlistener or move the script to a separate file.

**Option 1** *move the script tag below the target `div`*

```
<body>
    <div id="chartdiv"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       AmCharts.loadFile("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/22300.csv", {}, function (response) {

           /**
            * Parse CSV  ....
           */

       });  
   </script>
</body>
```

**Option 2** *wrap initialisation around `DOMContentLoaded`*

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
   AmCharts.loadFile("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-160/22300.csv", {}, function (response) {

       /**
        * Parse CSV  ....
       */

   });  
});
```

Comment: Caching should not be an issue here.

Comment: @martynasma Caching is not the real reason for his problem, but it is why it didn't occur the first time for him. Because it takes a while to load the file, the target `div` already exists when the `AmCharts.makeChart` is called. Because of caching the file loads immediately, and `AmCharts.makeChart` is called before the target div exists

Comment: @user6703592 I've updated my answer. I was on a little trip :) so excuse my late update

Comment: `AmCharts.makeChart` is an asynchronous function. It will wait for DOM to be ready before actually trying to instantiate the chart, hence wrapping it into additional `DOMContentLoaded` event is redundant. I bet it's something else with the setup, but I can't quite put my finger on it because the code works for me perfectly fine as it is.